# GEE: List operation and conditioning

Tags: google-earth-engine, list, conditional

I have a list of features containing two Polygons that belong to a MultiPolygon feature:

```
var polygon_lst = ee.Feature(MP_feat).geometry().coordinates(); //MP_feat is a MultiPolygon
```

I want to take every element of this list(two polygons), calculate their corresponding polygon.area() and return the index of the element whose polygon has the maximum area.

I think I need to use reducers at some point but I am not sure how.
Any comment on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would approach this problem.

1. Get a list of geometries from the `MultiPolygon`. This will be easier to deal with than a list of lists of coordinates.

   ```js
   var polygon_list = MP_feat.geometries();
   ```
2. Get a corresponding list with the area of each polygon using a `map`. Note that you need to specify a `maxError` when calculating area.

   ```js
   var area_list = polygon_list.map(function(f) {return ee.Geometry(f).area(1)});
   ```
3. Calculate the largest area in the list using a max reducer.

   ```js
   var largest_area = areas.reduce(ee.Reducer.max());
   ```
4. Get the index of the largest area identified above. Because the area list corresponds to the polygon list, this is also the index of the largest polygon.

   ```js
   var largest_index = area_list.indexOf(largest_area);
   ```
5. Optionally, get the largest polygon using the index.

   ```js
   var largest_polygon = ee.Geometry(polygon_list.get(largest_index));
   ```

Here's a script to demonstrate with some dummy data: https://code.earthengine.google.com/2100c0f01bf74e5a101b1f162de5cf58.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Correct and very informative for me as a GEE beginner :)

Comment: Indeed that one more step (.coordinates()) adds to the complexity rather than simplifying the procedure.